# Comment accorder le passé composé d'« envoyer » + infinitif avec le pronom « la »?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, accord, genre, passé-composé

En utilisant le pronom « la » avec la construction « envoyer  + infinitif » au passé composé, est-ce qu'on peut faire l'accord comme ci-dessous ?

> Je l'ai envoyée chercher.

Ou  doit-on toujours dire

> Je l'ai envoyé chercher

même si le pronom est « la » ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cette forme, « envoyer chercher », se construit de deux manière.

- envoyer chercher qqn : pas d'accord
- envoyer qqn chercher qqc  : accord

[Bescherelle](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Bescherelle_Le_dictionnaire_des_difficul/6ytQEAAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22l+%27+ai+envoy%C3%A9+chercher%22&pg=PA172&printsec=frontcover)

[image]

De nos jour on n'emploie pas beaucoup la première forme   et elle devient rare à l'oral.

- Je l'ai envoyé chercher (*français peu utilisé*)  → J'ai envoyé quelqu'un le/la chercher (*français contemporain*)

*Difficulté*

- je l'ai envoyé chercher par un concierge. (*Le concierge a été envoyé pour chercher « l » ; « l » est par example, Irène ou Antoine.*)
- je l'ai envoyé**e** chercher Jean.  (*« l » (Irène) a été envoyée pour chercher Jean*)
- je l'ai envoyé chercher Jean.  (*« l » (Antoine) a été envoyé pour  chercher Jean*)

Comment: *(Irène) a été envoyé**e** pour chercher Jean.*

Comment: "pas du tout à l'oral" : discutable, certes "j'ai envoyé quelqu'un la chercher" est beaucoup plus courant, mais on l'entend encore.

Comment: @guillaume31 « Devient rare à l'oral » serait plus exact ?